# Error response from daemon: readlink /var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/2U5H3EROYQLCC2NERR6OB7P4U5: invalid argument

Tags: docker

I am new to docker and using docker in my server. My server space got filled and after making spaces my docker cant take some command operation for example:

`docker inspect image_name`

my image is: **tbmg.samsmartcrm.com**

so when i apply:

```
docker inspect tbmg.samsmartcrm.com
```

gives error:

```
Error response from daemon: readlink /var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/2U5H3EROYQLCC2NERR6OB7P4U5: invalid argument
```

I ve tried to understand the error but could not able to understand. I have followed other too but they all say remove the image by using **prune** and rebuild but this will loose all data and settings which i did on that image for my site.

Is there any way to repair the image? using docker.

Comment: (Deleting the image shouldn't cause you to lose any data; you should be able to `docker pull` it from its registry again, or `docker build` it from source.)

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks for responding. can u be more precise i tried like that:

docker build -t tbmg.samsmartcrm.com -f "Dockerfile.txt" .

and i see ERRO[0035] Can't add file /var/lib/docker/containers/xxxx/xxbbdb-json.log to tar: archive/tar: write too long

Comment: how to do pull from registry or rebuild from source ? is it going to repair everything?

Comment: @DavidMaze can u plz answer?